# Solving a Tetris piece puzzle

Tags: algorithm

Given a grid of an arbitrary size (e.g. 20x20) that has some cells already occupied by Tetris shaped pieces, I would like to find a solution that gives me the most shapes I can fit onto the grid.

The rules are

1. No part of a piece can occupy a grid cell already occupied by part of another piece.
2. The algorithm must stop once it has taken 2 seconds.

This is a very tricky question, so I am not expecting working code, but ideas for approaches and algorithms/data structures would be very welcome.

Comment: Greedy algorithm followed by hill climbing gives you a decent start, and allows you to improve the result until time runs out.

Comment: I'd reach for https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver

Comment: (Max-)SAT, Integer-Programming or Constraint-Programming (aka the pillars of *exact* discrete-optimization). The CP-SAT solver mentioned above is a well-designed/packaged (hybrid) tool to try (although i would guess Integer-Programming with a set-packing like approach will be faster).

Comment: sounds like **bin packing** problem